# Удаление строки sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица и две функции - для записи и удаление строки. Последняя не работает. Как её починить?

```py
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect('filname.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connect.cursor()
# cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE users ('date', 'username', 'user_id')''')


def add_user(date, username, user_id):
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (date, username, user_id))
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()


def delete_user(user_id):  # FIX IT
    cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?''', (user_id))
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве параметров ожидается кортеж, поэтому замените:

```
(user_id)
```

на:

```
(user_id,)
```

PS следующая команда поможет разобраться:

```
print(type((user_id)))
```

Comment: В PS у вас две откр. скобки  и три закр.. Поправите?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо, набирал с телефона